# Instaling Ubuntu on KingStone DataTraveler 32GB doesn't work properly, why?

Tags: installation, usb-flash-drive, operating-systems, bootable-media

#### I have two of USB flash drives mentioned in title, brand new (~10 days). 
They support USB 2.0, 3.0, 3.1

I know how to install and boot different Linux distros from USB drives but this one gives me headache. 
For reasons that are beyond my understanding when I install Ubuntu or Debian (I have not tried other distros) on these specific devices they run extremely slow or don't work at all, also the installation takes couple times longer than when I used any other flash drive (old or new, 2.0 or 3.0). 
I am using virtualization software for installation so meanwhile I can use my computer.
I have tried installation several times, with LVM encryption and without, minimal installation and full etc. 
Benchmark off the device connected to a USB 3.0 port showed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/igUrr.png


For my own test I started copying a 8GB file, speed oscillated between 8 and 15 MB/s in a pattern of a steady wave.
So in conclusion I would not have seen anything wrong with these pen drives if not the soul purpose they were bought for, they seem just good and normal.

*Let me say it again, full instalation, not live-USB with rufus!*

My questions are: 
Have anyone met with such a thing? 
Why does this happen? 
Is there a special type or brand of pendrives that work as system drives? 

*Right now I am not even trying to solve the problem, but trying to understand it and avoid it in future.*

*my pendrive that works with Ubuntu pretty well is a SanDisk Ultra 64GB

Comment: How is it formatted? exFAT, for example., cannot be read by Ubuntu until an addtional driver is installed. Format FAT32 and try with Rufus again.

Comment: During installation process the flash drive is being formatted as the distro wants (I didnt force my partitioning scheme), so I don't think the problem is here. Especially that has worked on other devices.

Comment: That does not answer the question on file system format.

Comment: after installation it has FAT32, swap and ext4